# Generate full pdf report based on the search term used for a simple search

Tags: django, reportlab

I have a 'simple' search in my Django application that produces a list of all hits from the database, matching the search term. I want the user to be able to click a button which will generate a pdf report containing all the information from the hits that are listed in the simple search. Therefore, I was wondering if it's possible to 'store' the queryset that is generated by the search and pass it on to the function that is linked to the button 'Generate PDF report'.

The current search.html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}

{% if enzyme_list %}
    <h1>Search Results (matching enzyme terms):</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for enzyme in enzyme_list %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'gts:detail' enzyme.id %}">{{ enzyme.barcode }}, {{ enzyme.enzyme_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'gts:pdf_report' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Generate PDF report (WORK IN PROGRESS)</a>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <h1>No enzyme(s) found matching the specified search term.</h1>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

the views.py (both relevant views shown)

```
# The view that is used to generate the initial simplified list (template shown above)
class EnzymeList(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'enzyme_list'
    template_name = 'gts/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        #queryset_list = Enzymes.objects.filter(barcode='Tt_86')
        queryset_list = Enzymes.objects.filter(Q(barcode__icontains=query) |
        Q(enzyme_name__icontains=query) | Q(ec_number__icontains=query) | Q(enzyme_activity__icontains=query) |
        Q(organism__icontains=query) | Q(genbank_number__icontains=query) | Q(uniprot_accession__icontains=query) |
        Q(description_of_activity__icontains=query) | Q(experiment_details__icontains=query)
        )
        return queryset_list

# The view that is linked to the PDF generation (just the 'framework' for now).
def ReportView(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate PDF headers.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

    # Create the PDF object, using the response object as its "file."
    p = canvas.Canvas(response)

    # Draw things on the PDF. Here's where the PDF generation happens.
    # See the ReportLab documentation for the full list of functionality.
    p.drawString(100, 100, "Hello world.")

    # Close the PDF object cleanly, and we're done.
    p.showPage()
    p.save()
    return response
```

The urls.py that matches the url to the function

```
app_name = 'gts'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^get_result/$', views.EnzymeList.as_view(), name='enzyme_list'),
    url(r'^pdf_report/$', views.ReportView, name='pdf_report'),
]
```

I expected that I would be able to do something like `<a href="{% url 'gts:pdf_report' enzyme_list %}" class="btn btn-primary">` combined with a new function head `def ReportView(request, data):` in the template but this complains about missing the reverse match.

**-- Potential fix --**

I found a way to get it working but I am rather certain that this is not correct 'Django', I have just added the query to the return. Thereby, I can send it back to the pdf generation. The 'crappy' solution is presented below:

views.py

```
class EnzymeList(generic.ListView):
    context_object_name = 'enzyme_list'
    template_name = 'gts/search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get("q")
        #queryset_list = Enzymes.objects.filter(barcode='Tt_86')
        queryset_list = Enzymes.objects.filter(Q(barcode__icontains=query) |
        Q(enzyme_name__icontains=query) | Q(ec_number__icontains=query) | Q(enzyme_activity__icontains=query) |
        Q(organism__icontains=query) | Q(genbank_number__icontains=query) | Q(uniprot_accession__icontains=query) |
        Q(description_of_activity__icontains=query) | Q(experiment_details__icontains=query)
        )
        return (query, queryset_list)
```

search.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}

{% if enzyme_list %}
    <h1>Search Results (matching enzyme term: "{{ enzyme_list.0 }}"):</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for enzyme in enzyme_list.1 %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'gts:detail' enzyme.id %}">{{ enzyme.barcode }}, {{ enzyme.enzyme_name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <div>
        <a href="{% url 'gts:pdf_report' %}?q={{enzyme_list.0}}" class="btn btn-primary">Generate PDF report (WORK IN PROGRESS)</a>
    </div>
{% else %}
    <h1>No enzyme(s) found matching the specified search term: "{{ enzyme_list.0 }}".</h1>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %
```

}

**-- TL:DR --**

The question then specifically is how the search term should be handed to the `ReportView` function, assuming that my 'fix' is not Django-esque.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you move the query to a different function and call it anytime you need it.

```
def enzyme_search(query):
    return Enzymes.objects.filter(Q(barcode__icontains=query) |
        Q(enzyme_name__icontains=query) | Q(ec_number__icontains=query) | Q(enzyme_activity__icontains=query) |
        Q(organism__icontains=query) | Q(genbank_number__icontains=query) | Q(uniprot_accession__icontains=query) |
        Q(description_of_activity__icontains=query) | Q(experiment_details__icontains=query)
    )
```

Then in `EnzymeList` class,

```
...
def get_queryset(self):
    query = self.request.GET.get("q")
    return enzyme_search(query)

def get_context_data(self):
    context = super(EnzymeList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['query'] = self.request.GET.get("q")
    return context
...
```

And in `ReportView`

```
...
query = self.request.GET.get("q")
enzyme_list = enzyme_search(query)
...
```

Then in your anchor tag have

```
<a href="{% url 'gts:pdf_report' %}?q={{ query }}" class="btn btn-primary">
```

This should help you transfer the query across to the `ReportView`.